# MapBox RMMapView pixel to coordinates reports wrong lat/lng

Tags: geolocation, mapbox

Below is the code snippet I use to convert pixel to coordinates and vice versa.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(geoPoint.latitude, geoPoint.longitude);
[mapView setCenterCoordinate:currentLocation];
CGPoint centerScreenPoint = [mapView coordinateToPixel:mapView.centerCoordinate];
CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [mapView pixelToCoordinate:centerScreenPoint];
```

**geoPoint** on the first line is the current location reported by CLLocationManager. Although **centerScreenPoint** gives me 160, 284 which is the center point on iPhone 5, after running this code and dumping the values of **currentLocation** and **loc** I get two different coordinates.

How do these points come out different, any ideas?

Comment: How different are they? Is it a double precision issue since coordinates have many decimal places? Are they even close?